# MySQL only update rows if where clause is present

Tags: mysql

I believe I read somewhere that there is a mysql configuration setting that prevents rows from being updated via the console unless there is a WHERE clause present.

I haven't been able to find it in the documentation, does that option exist?

Comment: Is there any advantage of that? Considering I could always specify `WHERE 1`

Comment: From a real case. I asked my DBA to update a certain password to "11111", he quickly wrote the sentence and pressed the enter without putting a where statement...we have..many users

Comment: The advantage would be preventing me from updating all the rows in a table by mistake. There is no way to rollback transactions submitted directly via the console as far as I know.

Comment: yes trhere is, if u start a transaction. I teach my DBAs to always start with `start transaction` regardless what they do, and start to write the query from the where statement (serves two purposes:1. if pressed by mistake, it will only error out, 2. it will affect, hopefully, only what we intended for it to affect)

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon It forces you to explicitly put `WHERE 1` if you really mean it, so if you forget the `WHERE` clause by mistake Bad Things don't happen.

Comment: @Itay Moav: Actually that was perfect and free lesson, that doing something on production database without testing on dev/stage is a bad practice.

Comment: @zerkms yes, and we should all use design patterns, always, and eat healthy...theory is nice, not always in line with real world.

Comment: @Itay Moav: well, we either use it in a correct way or get in trouble :-) And each company makes its own decision which way to follow.

Comment: @zerkms - Look, I told a story (real one) which is suppose to be funny. Why would u assume I am not aware of the implications,  assume I give ALL the details...trying to educate someone in such a case is not polite.

Comment: @Itay Moav: I also wanted to try to educate, that **there is** a way of preventing such a mistakes. That's why I said that people either follow the best practices, or use some weird DBMS options to protect data from themselves.

Answer (score 13):

That is MYSQL SAFE UPDATE MODE.

***[Check here.](https://www.xpertdeveloper.com/mysql-safe-update/)***

And also the **[--safe-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates)** option.

Comment: It really should be called `--put-a-cork-on-my-fork` so you don't poke yourself in the eye with it.

Answer (score 8):

Just `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` before running your query.

See [MySQL tips](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-tips.html) regarding safe mode.

> For beginners, a useful startup option is --safe-updates (or --i-am-a-dummy, which has the same effect). It is helpful for cases when you might have issued a DELETE FROM tbl_name statement but forgotten the WHERE clause. Normally, such a statement deletes all rows from the table. With --safe-updates, you can delete rows only by specifying the key values that identify them. This helps prevent accidents.
>
> You are not permitted to execute an UPDATE or DELETE statement unless you specify a key constraint in the WHERE clause or provide a LIMIT clause (or both). For example:
>
> ```
> UPDATE tbl_name SET not_key_column=val WHERE key_column=val;
>
> UPDATE tbl_name SET not_key_column=val LIMIT 1;
> ```

Comment: Just to clarify, setting 'SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;' or starting MySQL with the --safe-updates option will only affect what I do in that session with that client, for example a web app accessing that same db can still update and delete rows regardless ...?

Comment: @deb If you're running a query, `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` should only affect the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

From the MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-tips.html

"4.5.1.6.2. Using the --safe-updates Option

For beginners, a useful startup option is --safe-updates (or --i-am-a-dummy, which has the same effect). It is helpful for cases when you might have issued a DELETE FROM tbl_name statement but forgotten the WHERE clause. Normally, such a statement deletes all rows from the table. With --safe-updates, you can delete rows only by specifying the key values that identify them. This helps prevent accidents.

[...]

You are not permitted to execute an UPDATE or DELETE statement unless you specify a key constraint in the WHERE clause or provide a LIMIT clause (or both)."